# javascript initialize property by using other properties

Tags: javascript, properties, enums, initialization

I don't know if there is `enum` in *JavaScript*. Here is my code:

```
var someObject = {
    UNLOCK : 0,
    LOCK : 1,
    state : this.UNLOCK,
};
```

It is not working. It looks like at this stage the `this` reference is not ready yet. How can I initialize property by other properties?

Comment: if you want to create Enums : Have a look [Enumerated types in JavaScript](https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/chapter-9/enumerated-types-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` in the context you've provided refers to the global object (`window`).

Simply add a new property on your object after it has been declared:

```
var someObject = {
    UNLOCK: 0,
    LOCK: 1
};

someObject.state = someObject.UNLOCK;
```

Comment: I have some experience with OO languages and it is more nature for me to initialize properties inside its declaration (of course there is no so-called declaration in js) or inside a constructor. Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: Not with simple object literals. If you're looking for something that's better encapsulated then you'd probably want to wrap everything up in its own class.